# Ambiguity in the definition of irreducible elements in a euclidean domain.

Tags: linear-algebra

In my linear algebra notes I have a definition of an irreducible element in a euclidean domain that states:

(Irreducible):

We say that an element p in an integral domain $A$ is irreducible
(in $A$) if $p \neq  0$,  $p$ is not a unit,  and the only divisors of $p$ (in $A$) are the elements of $A$ associated to $1$ or to $p$. Does this mean the *associates* of $1$ or $p$ or something else? Not sure what the author means here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the associates of 1 or p

Comment: Ok. My apologies on such a simple question I just didn't want to proceed with the wrong definition in my mind .

Comment: No need to apologise, that is why we are here. To help each other understand.